# how to make sorting by meta_key in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

in my search page wordpress sorting post by date.
But i want  sorting to meta_key in my template - imic_date (date of event).
I need to modify the search query, but where? 
code that should work. But... where I add it?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('custom-post-type'), 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => 'imic_date'
    );
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

(sorry for my english) :D

edit:

my search.php file:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 posts-archive">
        <?php
            if (have_posts()) :
                while (have_posts()):the_post();
                    echo'<article class="post">
                            <div class="row">';
                    if (has_post_thumbnail()):
                        echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
                        the_post_thumbnail('600x400', array('class' => "img-thumbnail"));
                        echo'</a></div>';
                    endif;
                    echo '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">';
                    echo '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h3>';
                    echo '<span class="post-meta meta-data">
                            <span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>' . get_the_time(get_option('date_format')) . '</span><br><span>Time:<br/>Date:<br/>Price:<br/>Venue:<br/>Category:</span><span></i><br/>'.imic_custom_taxonomies_terms_links().'</span> <span>';
                    comments_popup_link('<i class="fa fa-comment"></i>'.__('No comments yet','framework'), '<i class="fa fa-comment"></i>1', '<i class="fa fa-comment"></i>%', 'comments-link',__(' ','framework'));
                    echo'</span></span>';
                    //echo imic_excerpt(50);
                    echo '<p><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="btn btn-primary">' . __('More ', 'framework') . '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a></p>';
                    echo '</div></div>';
                    echo '</article>';
                endwhile;
            else:
                echo '<article class="post">';
                if (current_user_can('edit_posts')) :
                    ?>
                    <h3><?php _e('NOT', 'framework'); ?></h3>
                    <p><?php printf(__('NOT', 'framework'), admin_url('post-new.php')); ?></p>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <h3><?php _e('NOT', 'framework'); ?></h3>
                    <p><?php printf(__('NOT', 'framework')); ?></p>
                    <?php
                    echo '</article>';
                endif;
                ?>
            <?php
            endif; // end have_posts() check 
            pagination();
            ?>

        </div>
        <!-- Start Sidebar -->
        <?php 
            echo '<div class="col-md-3 sidebar">';
            dynamic_sidebar('sidebar');
            echo '</div>';
         ?>
        <!-- End Sidebar -->
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: did you try 'order_by' => array('imic_date'), ?

Comment: no, because i don't know, where add "'order_by' => array('imic_date') " - that's my  problem.

Comment: let me post as an answer so that you can easily read the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('custom-post-type'), 
    'order_by' => array('imic_date'),
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

edit,

modify your code like this,

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('custom-post-type'), 
    'order_by' => array('imic_date'),
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if ($loop->have_posts()) :
            while ($loop->have_posts()):$loop->the_post();
/** and then your code as used in original file */
```

Edit,

use the code bellow, it works ( I tested )

```
<?php $args = array(
'post_type' => 'event',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'imic_date')),
'order' => 'desc',
'paged'=>$paged,
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if ($loop->have_posts()) :
while ($loop->have_posts()):$loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

and your rest of the code here..

Comment: thank you my friend, but WHERE I should add this code?

Comment: you can add this code in search.php and use $loop in the while loop. If you don't have a search.php, you'll have to create one in your theme folder.

Comment: I have this file. I add my search.php in my first post. check it if you want. :)

Comment: well, sorry for my mistake. Just locate the code <?php if(have_posts()): ?> and past my code above it. And modify <?php if(have_posts()): ?> to <?php if($loop->have_posts(): ?> and your while loop like <?php while($loop->have_posts(): ?> and then setting up the post like <?php $loop->the_post(); ?> . Thats it

Comment: I modified my answer above. Just refer it

Comment: Thanks for help, but this code don't work. Now i have 0 results in all category and filter in my search. :/

Comment: in my opinion, now, wordpress can't find posts, becasue i see comunicat NOT. that shows up if there are no posts

Comment: 'post_type' => array('custom-post-type'),  - maybe it's bad.

Comment: My type post it's EVENT. So i modify your code 'post_type' => array('event'), 
    'order_by' => array('imic_date'),
    'order' => 'ASC', but don't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Format my date YYYY/MM/DD  - maybe i must convert it on the unixtime?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I was away for lunch. Let me update the above answer

Comment: Ok, now it's works. I change 4 parametrs and work, but pagination crashed. :D

Comment: can you see I modified again my last revision by addding paged'=>$paged . please try to add it, that will fix your pagination

Comment: yes, this repair my pagination, but now my search page only sorting.... :/ If i choose category MUSIC, it's don't work. earlier &category=music - in get, worked properly. Maybe be caused by new WP_Query? Old parametrs die?

Comment: umm... some one has described it here. Please see at the bottom http://melandri.net/add-a-category-filter-to-wordpress-search-form/ ( I didn't test it though)

Answer (score 0):

global $wpdb;

$tb_posts = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';

$tb_postmeta = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';

$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT $colums
                                FROM $tb_posts 
                                INNER JOIN $tb_postmeta 
                                ON  $tb_posts.ID =  $tb_postmeta.post_id 
                                WHERE $tb_postmeta.meta_key IN ('your_meta_key')
                                AND $tb_posts.post_status = 'publish'
                                ORDER BY post_date DESC
                                LIMIT 1
                                "
                                );

```
return $query;
```